# How to use glCreateShaderProgram?

Tags: c++, opengl

http://docs.gl/gl4/glCreateShaderProgram

Pseudo code:

```
const GLuint shader = glCreateShader(type);
if (shader) {
    glShaderSource(shader, count, strings, NULL);
    glCompileShader(shader);
    const GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
    if (program) {
        GLint compiled = GL_FALSE;
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled);
        glProgramParameteri(program, GL_PROGRAM_SEPARABLE, GL_TRUE);
        if (compiled) {
            glAttachShader(program, shader);
            glLinkProgram(program);
            glDetachShader(program, shader);
        }
        /* append-shader-info-log-to-program-info-log */
    }
    glDeleteShader(shader);
    return program;
}
else {
    return 0;
}
```

I didn't know that it is possible to compile several shaders at once. The problem that I have is that the documentation doesn't tell me how to call this.

What type should I specify if I want to compile a vertex + fragment shader? Initially I tried `glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER | GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);` but then it complained about two `main` functions. OpenGL probably interpreted two shaders as one shader.

Comment: The documentation states "for a single stage specified by `type`", so it's not too surprising that it doesn't work for multiple stages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to create multiple shaders at once. `glCreateShaderProgram` just does everything needed to create a shader for you (create, compile, link).

If you look at the documentation at opengl.org, you will see that you can only create one shader at a time. You can only specify one of the following `GLenum`s: `GL_COMPUTE_SHADER`, `GL_VERTEX_SHADER`, `GL_TESS_CONTROL_SHADER`, `GL_TESS_EVALUATION_SHADER`, `GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER`, or `GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER`.

I think you are right about what you are thinking. OpenGL is probably interpreting two shaders as one and that is not possible.

You can do this:

```
glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
```

Look at the **Description** field of the source I have provided. It will explain what further to do with the shader objects.

I am not sure why you can pass an array of strings. It could be if you had multiple small snippets of shader code in different source code files.

Source: https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glCreateShader.xhtml

Answer (score 8):

`glCreateShaderProgram()` only compiles and links a single shader. The last argument is an array of strings just like the corresponding argument for `glShaderSource()`, which is also used for specifying the source of **one** shader. Being able to pass multiple strings is just a convenience for both of those calls. For example, if you have your shader code as an array of strings (say one per line), you can directly pass them in, without a need to concatenate them first.

`glCreateShaderProgram()` is intended to be used in conjunction with program pipeline objects. This mechanism allows you to combine shaders from several programs, without a need to link them. A typical call sequence would look like this:

```
GLuint vertProgId = glCreateShaderProgram(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, 1, &vertSrc);
GLuint fragProgId = glCreateShaderProgram(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, 1, &fragSrc);

GLuint pipelineId = 0;
glGenProgramPipelines(1, &pipelineId);

glUseProgramStages(pipelineId, GL_VERTEX_SHADER_BIT, vertProgId);
glUseProgramStages(pipelineId, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT, fragProgId);

glBindProgramPipeline(pipelineId);
```

Answer (score 3):

From the linked documentation:

> glCreateShaderProgram creates a program object containing compiled and linked shaders *for a single stage specified by `type`*.

[emphasis mine]

What it means is that you cannot use it with a list of shaders targeting different parts of the rendering pipeline.

---

However, you could perhaps modify the sample implementation to cover that need for you. It would require to change the function signature by replacing the first parameter by an array of `GLenum` of `count`  elements, then turn the implementation into a loop on each pair `shader[i], strings[i]` to add them to the generated program, where `shader` is an array of shader ids associated with each source string separately.

Once each shader has been compiled, the code would then link the whole into a program, release all the shader ids, and return the program id (actual implementation left as an exercise).